# TCP and PF_RING

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, pf-ring

I was taking a look at using `PF_RING` for sending and receiving in my application.

If I plan to use `PF_RING` for maintaining a TCP connection, it looks like I'll need to manually "forge" the IP and TCP messages myself, as `pfring_send` sends raw packets.  Does this mean I'll have to manually reimplement TCP on top of `PF_RING`?

I understand there is a clear advantage for receiving using `PF_RING`, has anyone tried sending data with `PF_RING`? Is there a clear advantage over normal send calls?

note: I am not using DNA (Direct NIC Access), I am just using the kernel partial bypass with NIC aware drivers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes, you will have to manually build the TCP/IP messages from the ground up, MAC address and all. For an example take a look at [pfsend.c](https://svn.ntop.org/svn/ntop/trunk/PF_RING/userland/examples/pfsend.c) from [ntop.org](http://ntop.org/).

ntop.org has also made a [`PF_RING` user guide](https://svn.ntop.org/svn/ntop/trunk/PF_RING/doc/UsersGuide.pdf) available that contains explanations.

As for sending data using `PF_RING`, it is absolutely possible, the idea is to bypass any and all notion of what is actually data on the wire and send as fast as possible, see [wire speed traffic generation](http://www.ntop.org/solutions/wire-speed-traffic-generation/) from ntop.org. The only advantage it has over normal sending calls using the kernel for TCP/IP is that you can send data 1. faster and 2. completely unformatted onto the wire. 2 can be handy for example when you want to play back a previously captured packet/multiple packets onto the network.

---

Unless you have a specific use case that requires you to get access to the raw underlying data without kernel intervention there is absolutely no good reason to use `PF_RING` in any way. Your best bet would be to use the standard `socket()`'s that are available, in most cases the performance you can achieve with that is more than adequate.

What specific use case did you have in mind?

Comment: How about performance benefits versus normal socket send?  I am looking to eliminate inconsistencies in normal socket send.  Normally I see a this take 0->1 usec on average, but there are large outliers ( due to kernel activities) that sometimes result in up to 100 usecs.  I am trying to eliminate this system call.

Comment: You are re-implementing a TCP/IP stack in user space at that point, there is almost no case that it will be faster or more performant than one that is built into the kernel, specifically when it comes to resending packets on transmission failure, or taking care of all of the edge cases. What particular use case are you trying to optimise for? What is the end goal?

Comment: The end goal is to reduce outliers in send performance.  My application is "bursty" in the nature of sends (might send a bunch in a row and then wait for awhile before sending again -- awhile means 1ms+).  You are perhaps asking what my application does, which I am afraid I cannot say.

Comment: If your application is that sensitive to latency, use a userspace ring buffer and a separate (realtime priority) thread that drains the buffer by repeatedly calling send().  Then you don't have to care about a few microseconds of syscall variability.

Comment: @X-Istence hi,  How to send datas by PF_RING, if I don't want to use DNA?